# How to remove 'goto' from this loop?

Tags: c++, iteration

I have a loop that looks for 3 equal cards or 3 non equal cards and erases as it finds, if it doesn't find 2 equals/non-equals for the 1st chosen element it deletes that 1st element and goes to the other and so on...

Well, I'm using `goto` in this code to `break` from inside of two `for` loops and keep iterating throughout `while`.

To me, it makes good sense to use `goto` in this specific situation. But, since I'm not a very experienced programmer I think there would be a better way to do it, a more efficient way.

Is there? How would that be? not using `goto` in this case.

```
unsigned int i1 = 0;
while(gameCards.size() > 2)
{
    for(unsigned int i2=1; i2<gameCards.size(); i2++)
    {
        if(i2 == 2) continue;

        if(cannotMatch(gameCards.at(i1), gameCards.at(i2)))
        {
            for(unsigned int i3=2; i3<gameCards.size(); i3++)
            {
                if(cannotMatch3(gameCards.at(i1), gameCards.at(i2), gameCards.at(i3)))
                {
                    SetMatches++;
                    gameCards.erase(gameCards.begin()+i2,gameCards.begin()+i3);
                    goto findAnother;
                }
            }
        } else if(canMatch(gameCards.at(i1), gameCards.at(i2)))
        {
            for(unsigned int i3=2; i3<gameCards.size(); i3++)
            {
                if(canMatch3(gameCards.at(i1), gameCards.at(i2), gameCards.at(i3)))
                {
                    SetMatches++;
                    gameCards.erase(gameCards.begin()+i2,gameCards.begin()+i3);
                    goto findAnother;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    findAnother:

    gameCards.erase(gameCards.begin()+(i1++));
}
```

Comment: Move the inner code to a function, `return` from it. `goto` should be a last resort, like you've already sacrificed a small animal and it didn't work so you're out of options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set an extra bool condition to break outer for loop. You can also simplify your inner loops when you notice that they are essentially the same, just invoke different match3 functions:

```
while(gameCards.size() > 2)
{
    auto continue_outer_loop(true);
    for(unsigned int i2=1; continue_outer_loop && (i2<gameCards.size()); i2++)
    {
        if(i2 == 2) continue;
        auto const p_match_3_func
        (
            cannotMatch(gameCards.at(i1), gameCards.at(i2))
            ?
            &cannotMatch3
            :
            &canMatch3
        );
        for(unsigned int i3=2; i3<gameCards.size(); i3++)
        {
            if((*p_match_3_func)(gameCards.at(i1), gameCards.at(i2), gameCards.at(i3)))
            {
                SetMatches++;
                gameCards.erase(gameCards.begin()+i2,gameCards.begin()+i3);
                continue_outer_loop = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    gameCards.erase(gameCards.begin()+(i1++));
}
```

Comment: holy crap! time to go studying C++ again... it has changed so much.

Comment: @tesseractBird Well, except for `auto` this code should work even on pre C++11 compilers. Usual explicit way of declaring function pointers would just mess things up, but it should be possible even without auto.

Answer (score 0):

You can add guard variable and check for it in your loops. But will work, only when you do it at the end of loop as it is not real break.

```
while (mainLoop) {
    int goMain = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5 && goMain == 0; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5 && goMain == 0; j++) {
            if (wantExit) {
                goMain = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```